# what shall I do to kill a running script and go back to the prompt in python

Tags: python

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> each time to kill a running script and go back to the prompt. But then I lose the prompt, only to get "KeyboardInterrupt".

How should I kill a running script and get the python prompt back?

Comment: What do you mean by losing the prompt?

Comment: the thing with the >>, waiting for you to input the appropriate command

Comment: You don't get the full `KeyboardInterrupt` and `>>>` on the next line? Just the `KeyboardInterrupt` and then *nothing*?

Comment: yes. I only get the keyboardInterrupt. Not the >>>

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: Does it happen with all scripts or just with a specific script you run? Does it happen every time or sometimes with a specific script?

Comment: Do you mean that you're using Python's interactive mode on the command line, and ctrl+c is dumping you back into the shell?

Comment: i just encounter this problem today

Comment: after ctrl+c, there is pretty much nothing I can do. I have to kill the command window and start again.

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying that you want to launch the Python interactive terminal after a script finished running (both normally and by keyboard interrupt), then just launch Python with the `-i` tag. For example: `python -i <script-name> <script-args>`